# Having trouble running an if statement on a jquery ajax output

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

in my check.php I have an echo "ok";

however my if statement to check if the value is ok does not work. 
Basically I want to execute a javascript function after check.php looks for the email in the database.

```
    $.ajax({                
type: "POST",
 url: "check.php",
   data: "checkit=" + $("#checkEmail").val(),
    success: function(output){
    $("#userCheck").html(output);

            if(output == "ok"){
                alert("yay");
            }
        }


    });
```

Comment: @adam, first try to alert output and see what you are getting it there?? your ok might be upper case or lower case ..like that.do a null check and covert to lowercase and do a check

Comment: what is the value coming through as `output`?

Comment: @adam do one more thing as debugging , put your alert before the if block and see if you are getting into ajax success or not

Comment: Your 'ok' echo may be prefixed or suffixed by whitespace. Try if($.trim(output) == "ok")

Comment: all good answers.. I ended up using a a boolean value

Comment: wait... for some reason if it is true or ok it still runs the else statement as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest returning a JSON string rather than plain text. So your check.php should echo

```
{status: 'ok'}
```

then change your ajax handler to:

```
$.ajax({                
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    data: "checkit=" + $("#checkEmail").val(),
    success: function(response){
        $("#userCheck").html(response.status);
        if(response.status == "ok"){
            alert("yay");
        }
    }
}, 'json');
```

or you could even just return a boolean value:

```
{success:true}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$.ajax({                
    type: "POST",
    url: "check.php",
    dataType: "text", //<---
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    data: "checkit=" + encodeURIComponent($("#checkEmail").val()),
    success: function(output){

       $("#userCheck").html(output);
       if(output == "ok")
          alert("yay");

    }
});
```